# Xcopy variable declaration

Tags: batch-file

This cmd command gives me the file I am after .

> `dir /b /a-d "\\teams1.sharepoint.xx.com\teams\Contractcenter_Volume Direct Contracts\Shared Documents\"|findstr /b "CONTRACT" >"C:\AIRCR_CHANGE1_PATSY\aaafiles.tmp"`

Now how do I feed in this filename into xcopy to put in a nice batch file ?

xcopy "Source file path" "Destination File path"

Do I need to Open file, read filename and store as variable , then do xocpy "variable for source" " Destination File path"

Answer (score 1):

***Rewritten answer - original was wrong***

I don't see a need for a temp file at all, nor do I see a need for FINDSTR. You should be able to use XCOPY directly:

```
xcopy "\teams1.sharepoint.xx.com\teams\Contractcenter_Volume Direct Contracts\Shared Documents\contract*" "destinationFolder"
```

Comment: Also, the root folder (the `"\\teams1.sharepoint.xx.com\teams\Contractcenter_Volume Direct Contracts\Shared Documents\"` one) should probably be specified after `/r`.

Comment: @AndriyM - `*contract*` ? No, because OP's code use FINDSTR /B option. Including root path after FOR /R ? Not quite because not supposed to be doing a recursive search. I don't know why I introduced /R. But the path definitely should have been included within the IN() clause. But now that I realize no recursion, the whole thing is replaced with a simple XCOPY. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, both for the clarifications and for showing what a careless reader I am. :) I guess, under the circumstances, even `xcopy` wouldn't be needed, as `copy` could do just as well. It's true, though, that `xcopy` has this advantage over `copy` of creating the target path if it doesn't exist (in which case the `/I` switch should be used).

Comment: @AndriyM - Well I was certainly careless as well. I would never have discovered my errors if not for your 2nd comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FOR` command to read the file and store the content in a variable, which you would then use as your source or destination path.

E.g.

```
FOR /F %%I in (C:\AIRCR_CHANGE1_PATSY\aaafiles.tmp) DO xcopy %%I destinationPath
```

Note that thie above command will parse each line of your temporary file, and return the first token into `%%I`. The default separator for tokens is a blank character (space or tab). If the path to your source/destination file might contain spaces, you will have to specify a different separator, e.g.

```
FOR /F "delims=;" %%I in (C:\AIRCR_CHANGE1_PATSY\aaafiles.tmp) DO xcopy %%I destinationPath
```

The `FOR` command's help should help you tweak the command to suit your exact needs.